is there any way to use custom tailwind classes in JavaScript?
I want to use a tailwind class in JavaScript using querySelector()
this is my element
<div class="bg-indigo-500">

<div>

I want to use this element in my JavaScript as
document.queryselector(".mydiv")

I want to select it using a specific name

Are you asking whether you can use ".bg-indigo-500" to select your element, or whether you can add a class of your own to an element that has a Tailwind CSS class on it? Either of those questions has an answer that is simple to try and discover yourself...

Tailwind doesn't block you from using other class names.


console.log(document.querySelector(".mydiv"))
<div class="bg-indigo-500 mydiv">yup!</div>



On the other hand, Tailwind classes are just classes, so


console.log(document.querySelector(".bg-indigo-500"))
<div class="bg-indigo-500">yup!</div>



